# Mobicents Media Server failed to bind

Tags: sip, voip, mobicents, restcomm

I am running Mobicents Media Server and Restcomm in Oracle VirtualBox on the local machine. While making a call to 1234 I am getting following error.

```
2015-06-24 14:47:50,231 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483653 Started, message= CRCX mobicents/bridge/$@192.168.1.122:2427, call agent = /192.168.1.122:2727
2015-06-24 14:47:50,238 INFO  [UdpManager] (Thread-1) Failed trying to bind 192.168.1.122:65534
2015-06-24 14:47:50,244 INFO  [RtpConnectionImpl] (Thread-1) FormatsRTPFormats{0 AudioFormat[PCMU,8000,8,mono],8 AudioFormat[PCMA,8000,8,mono],101 AudioFormat[telephone-event,8000,mono],93 AudioFormat[Speex,16000,mono]}
2015-06-24 14:47:50,256 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483653 was executed normaly
2015-06-24 14:47:50,414 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483654 Started, message= CRCX mobicents/bridge/1@192.168.1.122:2427, call agent = /192.168.1.122:2727
2015-06-24 14:47:50,425 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-2) tx=147483654 was executed normaly
2015-06-24 14:47:50,433 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483655 Started, message= MDCX mobicents/ivr/1@192.168.1.122:2427, call agent = /192.168.1.122:2727
2015-06-24 14:47:50,447 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483655 was executed normaly
2015-06-24 14:47:50,533 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483656 Started, message= RQNT mobicents/ivr/1@192.168.1.122:2427, call agent = /192.168.1.122:2727
2015-06-24 14:47:50,557 INFO  [Play] (Thread-1) (mobicents/ivr/1) Start announcement (segment=0)
2015-06-24 14:47:50,598 ERROR [AudioPlayerImpl] (Thread-1) (mobicents/ivr/1) error occured
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.122:8080/restcomm/cache/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/c5fd1f13812a7d11cd9072b5a7c1d3455265a5724094920f929f4feb941c1061.wav
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.impl.resource.mediaplayer.audio.wav.WavTrackImpl.(WavTrackImpl.java:74)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.impl.resource.mediaplayer.audio.AudioPlayerImpl.setURL(AudioPlayerImpl.java:150)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.pkg.au.Play.startAnnouncementPhase(Play.java:116)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.pkg.au.Play.execute(Play.java:109)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.controller.Request.execute(Request.java:142)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.mgcp.tx.cmd.NotificationRequestCmd$Executor.perform(NotificationRequestCmd.java:213)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.scheduler.Task.run(Task.java:122)
    at org.mobicents.media.server.scheduler.Scheduler$WorkerThread.run(Scheduler.java:420)
2015-06-24 14:47:50,599 INFO  [Play] (Thread-1) Received URL can not be found , firing of
2015-06-24 14:47:50,603 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483656 was executed normaly
2015-06-24 14:47:50,873 INFO  [JitterBuffer] (Thread-2) Format has been changed: 0 AudioFormat[pcmu,8000,8,mono]
2015-06-24 14:47:58,193 INFO  [MGCP] (Thread-1) tx=147483657 Started, message= DLCX mobicents/bridge/1@192.168.1.122:2427, call agent = /192.168.1.122:2727
```

The restcomm.conf is as follows:

```
# Network configuration
NET_INTERFACE=eth0
PRIVATE_IP=192.168.1.122
SUBNET_MASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.255
# PUBLIC IP ADDRESS
STATIC_ADDRESS=192.168.1.122
```

The media server configuration is as follows:

```
<!-- Network interfaces definition -->
    <bean name="localhost" class="org.mobicents.media.server.io.network.UdpManager">
        <constructor>
            <parameter><inject bean="Scheduler"/></parameter>
        </constructor>
        <property name="bindAddress">192.168.1.122</property>
        <property name="localBindAddress">192.168.1.122</property>
        <property name="localNetwork">192.168.1.0</property>
        <property name="localSubnet">255.255.255.0</property>
        <property name="useSbc">true</property>
        <property name="rtpTimeout">0</property>
    </bean>
```

The restcomm.xml configuration is,

```
<!-- The location where the audio prompts are located. -->
        <prompts-uri>http://192.168.1.122:8080/restcomm/audio</prompts-uri>

        <!-- Cache settings. -->
        <cache-path>${restcomm:home}/cache</cache-path>
        <cache-uri>http://192.168.1.122:8080/restcomm/cache</cache-uri>


        <!-- The path where recordings made by the <Record> verb are stored. -->
        <recordings-path>file://${restcomm:home}/recordings</recordings-path>
        <recordings-uri>http://192.168.1.122:8080/restcomm/recordings</recordings-uri>

        <!-- The URL to the errors dictionary. -->
        <error-dictionary-uri>http://192.168.1.122:8080/restcomm/errors</error-dictionary-uri>

        <!-- The IP to use for out-bound SIP REGISTER requests. This is useful
            when you want to report a different IP than the one RestComm picked by default. -->
        <external-ip>192.168.1.122</external-ip>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check if the cache file exists: $RESTCOMM_HOME/standalone/deployments/restcomm.war/cache/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/c5fd1f13812a7d11cd9072b5a7c1d3455265a5724094920f929f4feb941c1061.wav
2. Check that Restcomm binds to 192.168.1.122:8080
3. Check that no firewall is blocking 192.168.1.122:8080

---

Even though the logs from MMS you provided is a very small subset of the actual logs for this calls, I believe that the problem is that local port 65534 is not free.

`INFO [UdpManager] (Thread-2) Failed trying to bind 192.168.226.245:65534`

At this point MMS is trying to bind the RTP port 65534 at the 192.168.226.245.

I suggest you stop Restcomm/MMS - run `ps -ef | grep java` to make sure that Restcomm/MMS actually stopped -, then start again and check with  `netstat -anp | grep 65534` if the port is busy and what is the process that has this port.

If this doesn't help, please provide pcap file (tcpdump -i any -w YOUR_FILE.pcap) and complete Restcomm and MMS log files (make sure you remove old logs before the test call).

George

Comment: Can you please provide me an email address where I can send the logs and pcap files?

Comment: It would be better if you can upload the files to an online file sharing service and provide here the link

Comment: There were two instances of media server running previously. Now the issue is when I dial 1234, it shows the cache file not found.

Comment: The log files you provided are for the case where the cache file is not found?

Comment: Also, what OS are you running? Did you set the VoiceRSS key at restcomm.conf? (Even though for 1234 you don't need TTS)

Comment: I am running on Centos 6.5 server. I don't have the VoiceRSS key.  This is for cache URL not found issue. I am  getting FileNotFoundException

Comment: The log files you provided are for the case where the cache file is not found or the previous where you had to MMS processes running? 
I am checking the Restcomm log and I cannot find a FileNotFoundException.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: The previous issue with bind is resolved. The mediaserver log shows FileNotFoundException for the cache URL.

Comment: Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: I changed my initial answer,  did you checked it? Can you check the three points I have there?

Comment: I can see a temp file named c5fd1f13812a7d11cd9072b5a7c1d3455265a5724094920f929f4feb941c1061.wav.tmp is available in the cache.

Comment: Please stop restcomm,  remove all files in the cache folder,  start again and test.  The file shouldn't be tmp.

Comment: I have tried it many times but it is the same error. FileNotFoundException

Comment: Can you check if a firewall is running? Also please send me the output of ifconfig, ps - ef | grep java and netstat - anp commands output.  cannot reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: From the output you sent I don't see Restcomm/MMS running. Instead I can see Asterisk running:
```root      1346     1  0 21:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk```
I am sure Asterisk will give you many headaches if its running in parallel with Restcomm so please make sure to stop Asterisk before running Restcomm/MMS.
Also, please check the command ```sudo iptables -L``` to see if there are any rules blocking traffic.
Do you think we can setup a remote session so I can check the instance?

Comment: I killed asterisk. You can connect now

Comment: Have you got connected?

Comment: I don't have the details for the remote connection.  Did you send them?

Comment: I don't have a static IP address.

Comment: You don't need a static ip, you can use teamviewer. Have you considered Restcomm docker image? Using the Restcomm docker image you don't have to worry about configuration etc. 
And you can run Restcomm docker image at Windows, Mac or Linux.
Check here: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/gvagenas/restcomm/dockerfile/
and here for how to install Docker https://docs.docker.com/installation/

Comment: I will try to use Docker image. BTW I am evaluating TelScale commerical product.

Comment: Otherwise you need to setup a remote access for me.

Comment: I have send the teamviewer access details to your email address.

Comment: I have used the docker image to install Restcomm latest version. I have tried to dial 1234.  It is getting timed out. This time I have used Ubuntu 15 desktop running on Oracle VM (Virtual Box)  The console log can be found at -> http://pastebin.com/snnEBuEp

Comment: @user3630807, I noticed that the logs is complaining about delay from the media server. Please make sure the media server is correctly configured and knows where to send the media. Please run -  "docker exec rc ps -ef | grep java" This will show to which port and Ip the media is bound.

Comment: I am not sure how docker works. I have tried the command "docker exec rc ps -ef | grep java". The response is - "Error response from daemon: no such id: rc"

Comment: Hi, please do the following, run "sudo docker images" this should give you a list of images you have on your setup. The list should include "docker.io/gvagenas/restcomm". Make a note of the Image Id. Then, run "sudo docker ps", this will show the list of containers. Make sure the following ports are present: 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535/udp. There should be a container with the Image Id you noted previously. Once you have that information, run "sudo docker exec CONTAINER_ID ps -ef | grep java" Note that you need to replace the container ID as mentioned above.

Comment: @Techpreneur, I have been able to reproduce your issue. I will get back to you with more information.

Comment: @Techpreneur, I update the Restcomm docker image with the patch to the MMS configuration that was causing the issue.

You should do: ```docker pull gvagenas/restcomm``` to update the Restcomm docker image and try again.

Please read carefully the documentation at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/gvagenas/restcomm/

Comment: The call to 1234 is getting connected but I cannot hear the message. Where can i find Restcomm logs for the docker image?

Comment: @Techpreneur, you can use "sudo docker logs restcomm". You might need to look into your configuration again. I suggest you stop the containers, and restart using the right configuration and making sure all the ports as mentioned in the doc page are set. With the changes made by GeorgeVagenas, you should now be able to hear audio.

Comment: I am able to make call to 1234 and get the response. I have mentioned STATIC_ADDRESS while running the docker image. Thanks GeorgeVagenas and TechKid for all the help.